# Users of some specific profile are not getting salesforce mail from Workflow, email alerts and test deliverabilty

Tags: workflow, profile

I have salesforce enterprise edition environment. In this any user is not getting mail from saleforce workflow or any kind of system mail from sfdc if we change users profile to system administrator then he will get mails.

Comment: is this a Sandbox? if yes you should check email deliverability setting

Comment: It is production environment i have also checked deliverability setting but after login another profile user except admin i am not getting mail from any server ?

Answer (score 2):

**Test the Deliverability of Emails Sent Through Salesforce**

When a user sends an email through Salesforce, the email is routed through one of a number of possible Salesforce IP addresses. If the email’s recipient blocks any of these IP addresses, the email might not be receieved.

It’s hard to test whether your customers are receiving emails from all possible Salesforce IP addresses. However, using the Test Deliverability feature, you can easily send an emails to yourself from each of the potential Salesforce IP addresses. If you receive all emails, then you aren’t blocking any of the Salesforce IP addresses.

1. From Setup, enter Test Deliverability in the Quick Find box, then select Test Deliverability.

   2 .Enter your business email address.

   3 .Click Send. Salesforce sends a test message from all IP addresses to your business email address. Each test message specifies the IP address from which it was sent.

   4.To make sure that you received all test messages, check your business email account.

If you get email from all address then you might need to raise a case. You can check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm&type=0)  and [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_test_email_delivery.htm&type=0).

Comment: Yeah I have checked  test deliverability from admin profile user i was getting all mail from 20 server while i logged in with any user which have not admin profile then then if i check test deliverability then i was not gettting anu mail from any server

Comment: @ErDheerajPandey Did you check their email address is correct and there is no firewall blocking salesforce email. Else you need to raise a case to Salesforce.

Comment: yeah that are correct if i will change there profile then they are able to get email from SFDC

Comment: @ErDheerajPandey Then you might need to raise a case.